# Why will setting a state of a variable to a constant array variable cause an infinite loop with a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This code below produces an infinite loop, maxing out the rendering.

I'm unsure why this is happening.

We have a similar problem in our enterprise codebase that has been resolved by changing the constant array to a state variable so it doesn't always change and by removing it from the useEffect because it won't change.

I'm guessing that by setting y, a different variable, to a constant array, it causes a rerender and x changes because the pointer value changes?

I'm not sure but I find this behavior odd.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';

const App = (props) => {
  const [y, setY] = useState([]);
  const x = [1001, 1002];

  setY(x);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(x);
  }, [x]);

  return <div></div>;
};

render(<App appName="User Details" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: So by using state, the array won't be reinstantiated with a new pointer value and it won't cause a rerender?

And by passing a constant array as a prop or non state variable it will always cause a rerender?

So to prevent this, is the pattern to just put all variables in state even if they never change (i.e constants)?

Or just to make sure non state variables are not included in useEffect?

Answer (score 2):

The truth is exactly the opposite from what @Anubhav Raj suggests.

Each time your component renders, x is an entirely new array by reference. And you are calling `setY` with it without any kind of wrapper (usually you'll call these setters in `useEffect` or a callback you create with `useCallback`, but in this case it doesn't matter because it will always happen on every render anyway).

Think of it this way:

```
let x = [1, 2];
x = [1, 2];
```

These are two different Array objects, even though the elements of both are the same. The fact that this is happening in two different runs of the same function makes it difficult to reason about, but essentially the same thing is happening.

Because you're calling `setY` with that new value, that queues up a rerender, causing the whole process to happen again.

Check out [this post](https://medium.com/codex/everything-you-thought-you-knew-about-react-functional-components-is-wrong-baf2dfc4f6f?sk=9fcf24e0f57a2dc8fca0ee9a34223bff) for more info.